DBus get stuck on compositor start
We use a Wayland compositor written in Qt5 to start and show some other applications written in Qt5 on an embedded Linux display computer.
All the applications and the compositor are using the DBus, or better QtDBus, to communicate.
When the compositor starts all the apps, the compositor freezes from time to time.
In the "freeze time" the CPU goes idle.
After searching for a while I found out that the freeze time per app start is around 25 seconds, which is the standard DBus timeout.
I have found some things to fight against the symptoms, but the problem is still there.
These are the symptom controls I have made:

reduce the DBus timeout in the session configuration to 1 second -> the compositor freezes only for 1 second per application start

more time between the application start -> the freeze happens not so often, but it happens

do not connect immediately to the application after it comes available on the DBus -> the freeze happens not so often, but it happens


Does anybody know a real solution to solve the DBus Timeout issue.
For me it seems there is some sort of race condition and/or deadlock when starting the apps.

The real solution would require finding the real problem first – have you tried investigating further to see what is being called via D-Bus, or whether dbus-daemon is trying to (or being asked to) start some service?

I have often used dbus-monitor to search for the isssue. When the problem occure there is silence on the DBus. I found no error before the problem occure and after the silenc there are some timeout errors.

Yes, but that just means the problematic call was issued immediately before the silence. Look for any calls that didn't produce a reply (maybe using Bustle).
